# Google Sheets Hiding Rows using checkboxes Apps Script

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

Sort of Newbie so please be kind.

I have been working on this code for hours and I have been making progress ... I think lol ... but I now seem to be stuck.

You will see in the photo [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zJwID.png) with the idea that I am trying to accomplish.
I have a list of different areas of a house that would need to be renovated. Under each area would be all the items that would need to be selected.
I would like for example if I deselect the Kitchen section that the entire section of rows under would be hidden and if re-selected they would open back up.

I have figured out how to hide the section if I go a count each row and indicate I would like x number of rows hidden. However multiple people will be using this and I would like the functionality of adding additional areas or items to each list without having to rewrite code.

I just can't figure out how to get it to count the number of rows to the next checkbox in column A so everything between will looks like [This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOAfi.png) once the kitchen area is unchecked.

Any who, this is the code i have thus far:

If someone can please please help me wih this I would greatly appreciate it.

```
function onEdit(e) {
  var rs = e.range.rowStart + 1;
  var ccc = e.range.getCurrentCell();
  var nd = ccc.getNextDataCell(SpreadsheetApp.Direction.DOWN).getA1Notation().slice(1) - 1;
  if (e.range.columnStart != 1) return;
  if (e.value != "TRUE") {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().hideRows(rs, nd);
  }
  else if (e.value != "FALSE") {
    SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().showRows(rs, nd);
  }
}
```

Comment: Event object `e` of `onEdit(e)`, `e.range` is the range object. In this case, I think that `getCurrentCell()` method cannot be used as `e.range.getCurrentCell()`. But in your question, you say `I just can't figure out how to get it to count the number of rows to the next checkbox in column A so everything between will looks like This once the kitchen area is unchecked.`. So I'm worried that you might have miscopied your script. How about this? And, if [your provided image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gOAfi.png) is not your expected result, can I ask you about the output situation you expect?

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve the same behavior without any script, by grouping the rows. It will be faster and simplier.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

#### Hiding Rows in column B if they are checkboxes

The function assumes a one row and one column offset for the checkboxes in columnB from the checkboxes in columnA and the hides rows as long as it finds checkboxes in the rows.  When there is not a checkbox it stops

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == 'Sheet0' && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.value == "TRUE") {
   if(e.range.offset(1, 1).getDataValidation().getCriteriaType() == "CHECKBOX") {
     let r = e.range.offset(1,1).getRow();
     let i = 0;
     do{
       sh.hideRows(r + i++);
     }while(e.range.offset(1 + i,1).getDataValidation().getCriteriaType() == "CHECKBOX")
   }
  }
}
```

Demo:

[image]

I thought about doing it this way as I went to sleep and it is much faster

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == 'Sheet0' && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.value == "TRUE") {
   if(e.range.offset(1, 1).getDataValidation().getCriteriaType() == "CHECKBOX") {
     let r = e.range.offset(1,1).getRow();
     let i = 0;
     do{
       i++;
     }while( e.range.offset(1 + i,1).getDataValidation() && e.range.offset(1 + i,1).getDataValidation().getCriteriaType() == "CHECKBOX")
     sh.hideRows(r,i)
   }
  }
}
```

#### Hiding and Showing

```
function onMyEdit(e) {
  const sh = e.range.getSheet();
  if (sh.getName() == 'Sheet0' && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.value == "TRUE") {
   if(e.range.offset(1, 1).getDataValidation().getCriteriaType() == "CHECKBOX") {
     let r = e.range.offset(1,1).getRow();
     let i = 0;
     do{
       i++;
     }while( e.range.offset(1 + i,1).getDataValidation() && e.range.offset(1 + i,1).getDataValidation().getCriteriaType() == "CHECKBOX")
     sh.hideRows(r,i)
   }
  }
  if (sh.getName() == 'Sheet0' && e.range.columnStart == 1 && e.value == "FALSE") {
   if(e.range.offset(1, 1).getDataValidation().getCriteriaType() == "CHECKBOX") {
     let r = e.range.offset(1,1).getRow();
     let i = 0;
     do{
       i++;
     }while( e.range.offset(1 + i,1).getDataValidation() && e.range.offset(1 + i,1).getDataValidation().getCriteriaType() == "CHECKBOX")
     sh.showRows(r,i)
   }
  }
}
```

Demo:

[image]

Comment: THANK YOU, THANK YOU THANK, YOU!

This works perfectly, I am however disappointed in myself for being so far off with the code :(

Comment: Well there may be other ways of doing this.  My mind just sort of locked on this approach.